# not able to hear voice in YouTube videos

Tags: youtube

I am not able to hear the voice in my YouTube videos, but I can hear the music in the video and my head phones work perfectly with other sort of videos and i can perfectly hear songs also and the problem is with all video on YouTube. so suggest me some remedy please.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your input in your streaming/recording application so that it's using the proper recording device. Also make sure that it's setup as the default recording device.

You may need to open up a ticket with youtube if your videos play your voice on your local machine fine (prior to upload). They have auto-detecting sound software that may be taking it out.